# Inject a service inside another service in Nestjs?

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I need something like this:

```
@Injectable()
class TokenVerification {
    verify(token: string) {
        //...
    }
}

//Inject TokenVerification into MailService
@Injectable()
export class MailService {

    public constructor(private tokenVerification: TokenVerification) {}

    public sendMail() {
        // ...
    }

    public verifyEmail(token: string) {
        this.TokenVerification.verify(token);
    }
}
```

Later, I will inject the `MailService` into a controller using a module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [],
  providers: [MailService],
  controllers: [SomeController],
})
export class SomeModule {}
```

How can I achieve injection between classes or services in NestJS? :)

Comment: have you read the whole docs? this is pretty basic stuff in nest... Just add `TokenVerification` into the `providers` array of the `SomeModule` module.

Comment: @Micael Levi I'm new to DI or IoC concepts, now I understand better, it was easier than I thought, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the services to SomeModule providers like you did in your question example and in the some.service.ts

you use it this way in your constructor

```
constructor(
 private readonly mail: MailService,
) {}
```

Comment: service is undefined in this case for me